# Anime.js and MathML

Tags: mathml, anime.js

I just discovered anime.js and it feels like the right tool for what I need (animating some web tutorials in 2D).
The problem is that I'm using MathML (part of the HTML5 standard), which uses "math" tags.

HTML

```
<math>
    <mrow>
        <msqrt>
            <mrow>
                <msup class="ml4">
                    <mi class="letter">b</mi>
                    <mn>2</mn>
                </msup>
            </mrow>
        </msqrt>   
    </mrow>
</math>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="anime.min.js"></script>
<script>
    anime.timeline({loop: true})
    .add({
        targets: '.ml4 .letter',
        opacity: [0, 1],
        scale: [0.2, 1],
        duration: 800
    });
</script>
```

When I try to simply animate letters within a math tag (opacity, scale, duration), I get:

**If I use anime.min.js (2.0)**

In Firefox

```
"TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got undefined" 
-> anime.min.js:9:136
```

In Safari

```
"TypeError: a.style is not an Object. (evaluating 'b in a.style')"
 -> "B" -> anime.min.js:9:145
```

**If I use anime.js (2.0)**

In Firefox

```
"TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got undefined"
-> anime.min.js:346:5
```

In Safari

```
"TypeError: a.style is not an Object. (evaluating 'b in a.style')"
-> "getCSSValue" -> anime.min.js:346
```

In both cases, the math formula appears just fine but the animation isn't working.
I tried previous versions of anime.js with the same result.

I toyed with the code and the animation comes back + the error message goes away on Firefox and Safari if I get rid of the "math" tag. But then, of course, the math formula is a mess, which is of no help.
But it seems the issue is related to this math tag alone.
I also tried to style, unstyle the math tag and the inner tags but the error remains.

I could understand that this tag is unsupported by animate.js but the animation works just fine and without any error within my Coda2 (web dev software) on Mac, on its own dedicated browser.
So this seems very browser dependent but so far it's the only browser that seems to consider the script as valid.

I haven't found anything on the web that is addressing both anime.js and the MathML so it's hard to say if it's a bug or an error on my part.

Thank you.

https://jsfiddle.net/bt4u23rh/1/

Comment: The style API does not work on Mathml elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a wrapper, or you can modify the function `getCSSValue` on the `animejs` library. Basically that function looks for the `style` property for that specific target.

```
function getCSSValue(el, prop) {
  if (prop in el.style) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue(stringToHyphens(prop)) || '0';
  }
}
```

When the code reaches the `if` line, your `mi .letter` doesn´t have that attribute and the call to the function fails and bubble up.

Using the proposed workaround, you can create a `div` that contains your `mathML` tags:

```
<div class="letterWrapper">
<math>
  <mrow>
    <msqrt>
      <mrow>
        <msup class="ml4">
          <mi class="letter">b</mi>
          <mn>2</mn>
        </msup>
      </mrow>
    </msqrt>   
  </mrow>
</math>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bt4u23rh/2/

Comment: Glad to help @BachirMessaouri :)

Comment: Just one thing. Although this allows me to target the whole formula successfully, is there any way to target a sub element? I mean, if I need to only apply the animation to the <mi> tag for instance.
I tried to surround it by a div or any standard html5 tag but with no success.
Any workaround in this case?
That's all I would need.

Comment: It has strange behaviors using it that way.
If the a remains as an inline element, the animation won't translate for instance.
If the a is changed to a block element, it works beautifully but then, the letter is duplicated for some reason (the initial b remains in place while another instance of it is animated on top of it).
And if the a is changed to inline-block, then it totally works but then we get a position offset and the other elements just don't behave.
So it feels like it's just not very usable. That is kind of annoying but it is what it is. Anyway, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Problem solved like this (padding would have been a pain to manage): 
I added the "display:block" to the a tag and put the color of its parent to transparent. It works like a charm.
https://jsfiddle.net/bt4u23rh/8/ You really led me to the right path, thanks!